# C# API library and logging to PowerShell's WriteVerbose()

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, logging

I'm building a DLL in C# that I will be consuming with several different projects - so far, I know of a WPF application and a (binary) PowerShell module. Because the core business logic needs to be shared across multiple projects, I don't want the PowerShell module itself to contain the core logic. I'd just like to reference my primary library.

I'm struggling to figure out how to implement a clean logging solution in my core DLL that will be accessible via PowerShell's [WriteVerbose()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.writeverbose?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) method. Without this, I can provide verbose output to PowerShell about PowerShell-specific things, but I can't provide any verbose output about "waiting for HTTP request" or other features that would be in the core DLL.

Here's a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace CoreApp
{
    public class AppObject
    {
        public AppObject() {}

        public int DoStuffThatTakesForever()
        {
            // Assume logger is a logging object - could be an existing
            // library like NLog, or I could write it myself

            logger.Info("Doing step 1");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            logger.Info("Doing step 2");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            logger.Info("Doing step 3");
            Random r = new Random();
            r.Next(0, 10);
        }
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Separate VS project that references the CoreApp project

using System.Management.Automation;
using CoreApp;

namespace CoreApp.PowerShell
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Invoke, "ThingWithAppObject"]
    [OutputType(typeof(Int32))]
    public class InvokeThingWithAppObject : Cmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        public AppObject InputObject {get; set;}

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            // Here I want to be able to send the logging phrases,
            // "Doing step 1", "Doing step 2", etc., to PowerShell's
            // verbose stream (probably using Cmdlet.WriteVerbose() )
            int result = InputObject.DoStuffThatTakesForever();

            WriteObject(result);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I provide verbose PowerShell verbose output without tightly binding the core library with the PowerShell module?

Comment: When you say logging, you mean at the console only?  In PowerShell, you don't see verbose output unless you specify the `-Verbose` flag and you utilize an advanced function/script (utilizes `[CmdletBinding()]` or `[Parameter()]` attributes)

Comment: This should be identical behavior to an advanced PowerShell function - I want to provide logging to the Verbose output stream. I'm aware that the output won't be visible unless -Verbose or $VerbosePreference is set, and that's my design goal. I'm planning to make the cmdlets support CommonParameters, and I'd like to support the -Verbose switch (and probably -Debug as well if I can get this working).

Comment: Why don't you call the verbose method from your program?  Or is that your root problem?

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. The core DLL knows nothing about PowerShell, so it can't access the Cmdlet.WriteVerbose() method. I need a way to "redirect" its logging to the verbose output stream.

Answer (score 2):

I'm definitely open to other solutions, but here's how I ended up solving it:

In the core library, I created an **ILogger** interface with methods for Info, Verbose, Warn, etc. I created a DefaultLogger class that implemented that logger (by writing everything to the attached debugger), and I gave this class a static singleton instance.

In each method that I wanted logged, I added an optional ILogger parameter, and added a line to use the default logger if necessary. The method definitions now look like this:

```
public int DoSomething(ILogger logger = null)
{
    logger = logger ?? MyAppLogger.Singleton;

    // Rest of the code
    Random r = new Random();
    return r.Next(0, 10);
}
```

I had to do this for each method because *the PSCmdlet.WriteVerbose() method expects to be called from the currently running cmdlet*. I couldn't create a persistent class variable to hold a logger object because each time the user ran a cmdlet, the PSCmdlet object (with the WriteVerbose method I need) would change.

Finally, I went back to the PowerShell consumer project. I implemented the ILogger class in my base cmdlet class:

```
public class MyCmdletBase : PSCmdlet, ILogger
{
    public void Verbose(string message) => WriteVerbose(message);

    public void Debug(string message) => WriteDebug(message);

    // etc.
}
```

Now it's trivial to pass the current cmdlet as an ILogger instance when calling a method from the core library:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Invoke, "ThingWithAppObject"]
[OutputType(typeof(Int32))]
public class InvokeThingWithAppObject : MyCmdletBase
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, Position = 0)]
    public AppObject InputObject {get; set;}

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        int result = InputObject.DoSomething(this);
        WriteObject(result);
    }
}
```

In a different project, I'll need to write some kind of "log adapter" to implement the ILogger interface and write log entries to NLog (or whatever logging library I end up with).

The only other hiccup I ran into is that WriteVerbose(), WriteDebug(), etc. cannot be called from a different thread than the main thread the cmdlet is running on. This was a significant problem, since I'm making async Web requests, but after banging my head on the wall I decided to just block and run the Web requests synchronously instead. I'll probably end up implementing both a synchronous and an async version of each Web-based function in the core library.

This approach feels a bit dirty to me, but it works brilliantly.

Comment: Thanks for tips. About to have a go at something like this.  Feels like there should be an ILogger in the automation package and an approved method for this. I recently chose to just .Result all my Tasks as you can't rely on awaiting inside an async void method.

Comment: Could you have an app service newed up in your BeginProcess()? Pass in an applogger for life of that instance? Should cover all instances of ProccessRecord and not need to pass ilogger to each method? I guess this is little different as the logic is a behavior of a parameter, not a behavior of an appService